# How to store the value of <input type="range"> in localstorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a website with an opacity layer on top of it. I succeeded in making the opacity of the upper layer adaptable with a range input. The value of the opacity is being stored in localstorage, so that it will remain when the page is reloaded. Although, the value of the range input will reset every time the page is reloaded. I want to keep the value of the range input the same as before the reload. I know I have to use localstorage to save the value of the range input, but I do not know how. Could anybody help me with that?

This is my HTML code:

```
<div id="layer"></div>

<div id="BackGroundSlider">
      <input id="contrast" type="range" value="0" max="1" min="0" step="0.01" />
    </div>
```

This is my css code:

```
#layer {
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:-1;
  opacity: 1;
  margin:0;
 }

#BackGroundSlider{
  z-index:0;
}
```

This is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#layer").css('background-color', localStorage.getItem("#layer"));

$("#contrast").on('input', function() {
$('#layer').css('background-color', "rgba(255,255,255," + $(this).val() + 
     ")");
     var status = $("#layer").css('background-color');
     localStorage.setItem("#layer", status);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be to update your range in the localstorage whenever it changes. And then you are sure to always get the last value before reload.

```
$("#contrast").on('input', function() {
  ...
  var range = $(this).val();
  localStorage.setItem("range", range);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty much on the right track. Not sure what the problem is since you seem to have the right idea. With that said, you have your range value stored in  `localStorage` and you can access it. I recommend thinking this through in terms of the entire scope - when should the value be used, e.t.c.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#layer").css('background-color', localStorage.getItem("#layer"));

$("#contrast").on('input', function() {
$('#layer').css('background-color', "rgba(255,255,255," + $(this).val() + 
     ")");
     var status = $("#layer").css('background-color');
     let rangeValue = $(this).val();
     localStorage.setItem("rangeValue", rangeValue);
     const currentRangeValue = localStorage.getItem("rangeValue");
     // use currentRangeValue
     
    });
});
```

```css
#layer {
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:-1;
  opacity: 1;
  margin:0;
 }

#BackGroundSlider{
  z-index:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="layer"></div>

<div id="BackGroundSlider">
      <input id="contrast" type="range" value="0" max="1" min="0" step="0.01" />
    </div>
```